# Expected value proof: $E(cX)=c\,E(X)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

I get it how to prove this property in discrete and continous cases, bet I need to prove it in this case:

Let $X$ be random variable $X: \Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, and $c\in\mathbb{R}$. $X$ is intergrable.

Prove that $cX$ is integrable for every $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $E(cX)=c\,E(X)$.

I am using limits, and I let $X$ be non-negative and $(Xn)$ is monotonously getting bigger, then:

$$E(cX)= \lim_{n \to 1} E(c\cdot Xn)=c\lim_{n \to 1} E(Xn)=c\,E(X)$$

But this is probabbly incorrect, because I have a hint that there are two cases, when $c<0$ and when $c\geq0$. I somewhere need to use this equation:

$$0 = E(X − X) = E(X) + E(−X)$$

I can’t figure it out.

Comment: This follows immediately from linearity of the Lebesgue integral. There is no need to distinguish between the discrete and continuous cases, and in fact doing so only leads to a lesser understanding of the actual concept.

Answer (score 2):

The usual proof of this fact comes from the fact that [integration is linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Linearity). We define the expectation to be $\mathbb E[f(x)] \equiv \int f(x) p(x) dx$. So,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[cX] = \int cx dx = c \int x dx = c \mathbb E[X]
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh, sorry, as I am translating this from my native language, I did a big mistake.  I need to prove, that for c∈R, c is integrable and  E(cX)=cE(X).